# How can I use 'emacsclient' as $PAGER in eshell with pipe? or any better PAGER which works well with eshell?

Tags: eshell, environment

When I typed `git diff` in `eshell`, it has weird attribute such like print `:` in every single line, cannot scroll back, and so on.

I think this is because the default eshell env PAGER is set as `less`, and I checked with typing `echo $PAGER` which returns a result, `less`.

So, as I wrote `(setenv "VISUAL" "emacsclient")` in my `init.el`, I added `(setenv "PAGER" "emacsclient")` line. However, it failed and I found that `emacsclient` doesn't support pipe, which means `echo aaaa | emacsclient` ended with an error. and I heard about magit, but I don't think it is a general solution.

Is there any solution to set $PAGER to work properly with `eshell`?

or How can I make `emacsclient` to support pipe in eshell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to disable the `PAGER` entirely:

```el
(setenv "PAGER" "")
```

This dumps all output directly to the eshell buffer, so you can use normal Emacs navigation commands to navigate the output.

You can even disable it for an individual command by running the command as:

```
PAGER="" <command>
```